# Security with JApplet loading Library

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, japplet

I've created a JApplet that uses the library JFreeChart (and JCommon). My application is a client-server like. I make a request for the chart the server creates it and return a JPanel containing the chart. This particular JPanel is an instance of a class (ChartPanel) that is a subclass of JPanel.
Now the problem is this: when i read the JPanel from the server i've got this stack trace http://pastebin.com/WnLcp9kQ (You can see my classes at line 36)
What it means? is related to the fact that i'm using the two (JFreeChart and JCommon) jars as external libraries?
Here you can see my project structure from which i've created the jar http://i45.tinypic.com/zw136p.png

Thanks.

Comment: Are your JARs signed? See [*What Applets Can and Cannot Do*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).

Comment: `KMeans$TabbedPane.learningFromDBAction(KMeans.java:144)`  What is line 144 of that class?

Comment: is this: chart = (JPanel)in.readObject();

Answer (score 0):

I can't even think of where to begin with this.

First, don't pass Swing components over the network.  This is just messy and will cause never ending problems.

The problem you are facing relates to the expectations of a component created within a different context.  The component is then violating the restrictions of the applet's security manager.

It would be (slightly) better to pass the JFreeChart object back and then apply it to the panel yourself, assuming it's not JFreeChart trying to link to a native library.

A better solution would be to pass the series data back to the client and construct the whole cart on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...you've understand what i'm doing! ;)
I create the chart on the server and then i pass the JPanel that contain the Chart to the client. I think i will use your last solution.
EDIT:
I'm having lot of problem with the JApplet. If i debug it works "correctly" (but with the chart problem) if i not debug it then it seem to freeze.
What you think of signed jar? As Andrew Thompson says above?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! It works! I've passed the data from the server to the client and it works! But it works in a strange way, cause if i debug the server and run the japplet of the client all is ok. if i run the japplet of the server and then i run the japplet of the client i got this:
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver**
This is the first case of non-deterministic software maybe! :D

Comment: Is the driver jar linked into the client applet? As for signed jars, this is not a bad idea, but it depends on what is causing he security violation in the first place & how tight the clients security policy is

Comment: Also, make sure tat 1. The client applet contains a class path property in its manifest & that it can downloaded from the server

Comment: But how do you explain the fact that if i debug the code all works and if i run it i got that exception?

Comment: I've found the problem. http://pastebin.com/mSCNjaKr
I get this when the client applet reach this: **result = (String)in.readObject();**
I don't know why but i get this exception only if the server is runned in the browser and not with the appletviewer, very strange!
Maybe because of applets security policies?

Comment: But i think is related to the driver exception on the server side!

Comment: I've resolved. I've signed the server applets and included the jars that the applet uses in the **archive** folder.
Now i've this problem (the never ending story): After i accept the applet certificate in the browser, then appears a new dialog but it is completely empty just like this: http://i45.tinypic.com/3465bmc.jpg

Now i don't know what to do!

Comment: You need to check the Java Console to see what it's outputting.  Also, I'm now very confused, the "sever" shouldn't be running on the client side or am I just reading this wrong

Comment: You're right but i'm running them on the same machine. is just for a demonstration.

Comment: It looks like the client program is trying to load the jdbc driver, which from what i can tell, you don't need/want to do

Comment: I've resolved using a GUI for the server and not an applet that is conceptually better (related to the meaning of a server). thanks for your advices! ;)